# Assigning temporary object to the invoking object

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm doing an exercise from a book. I have a class (named Golf) and one of its the functions should pass some data to the constructor to create a temporary object, and assign the temporary object to the invoking object, which is *this.
Here is the code:

```
Golf::Golf(const std::string name, int hc)
{
    fullname = name;
    handicap = hc;
}

int Golf::setgolf()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.sync();
    if (name == "")
        return 0;
    else
    {
            int handicap;
            std::cout << "Enter the handicap: ";
            std::cin >> handicap;
            *this = Golf(fullname, handicap); //this line doesn't set the values
            return 1;
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. I haven't found any sollution on the internet. 
How should I do this?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: it should change the two values, but it doesn't change them. I can't define it more deeply.

Comment: Is the constructor setting up the members? Do you have an assignment operator defined? Have your members a working assignment operator?

Comment: I edited the question. The book haven't discussed operator overloading so I shouln't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*this = Golf(fullname, handicap);
```

That will initialise the temporary's `fullname` from the current object's `fullname` field, *not* from the name that's just been read from input. You probably want:

```
*this = Golf(name, handicap);
```

Alternatively, you could rename the local variable to hide the member, although some people disapprove of that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few preconditions for `*this` being a viable destination for assignments:

1. The member function cannot be `const`.
2. The assignment operatot (`... operator=(Golf ...)` with the `...` suitably repaced) is not deleted.
3. Either the generated assignment or the explicitly defined assignment does the right thing.

The default assignment operator is often OK: it does a memberwise assignment. You may need your own version, e.g., if you need to maintain resources (i.e., when you also have a copy constructor and a destructor). Another reason for an assignment operator is the need to make assignment strongly exception-safe but one of the member assignments possibly throwing an exception, e.g., if it is a `std::string` or a `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, creating object in itself is well-known way that is ised in singletones, but there was used static method:

```
class Golf{
private:
    Golf *p;
    Golf(){}
public:
    static Golf* instance(){
        if(p == NULL)
            p = new Golf();
        return p;
    }
}
Golf::p = NULL;
```

On first call of Golf::instance() you create new object, the next calls only return pointer to existing object.

Comment: What on earth do singletons have to do with a question about creating and assigning from a temporary?